# Is it possible to work on a ASP.NET application on Visual Studio 2015 and VS Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I was unable to find information about this on google or stack overflow. Ideally I would like to be able to work on web application on my MacBook while I'm not at home and then use GitHub to make the code available on my Windows computer while I'm home. My current problem is that dotnet command doesn't create a project file that can be opened by VS on my Windows machine. Is there a way to switch between computers easily without using VS Code on Windows?

Comment: This does answer my question ^^ Thanks!

Comment: VS 2015 can open project.json. It gona create a .xproj. You can create a blank solution and add your project.json files in it. VS Code opens folders so it's compatible.